# Making a REST AJAX call from Basic Page

Tags: 7, ajax, services

The following successfully calls a REST Services Module endpoint when contained in a module but I cannot get it to work within the script tags of a basic page.

```
(function ($) {

  var myapi = {
    'apiPath': '/api/award'
  };

  // REST functions.
  myapi.create = function (award) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost/testsite/api/award',
      data: JSON.stringify(award),
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json'
    });
  };

  myapi.create({ award : 'The Award' });

}(jQuery));
```

I am wondering if it is even possible to embed AJAX calls in a Basic Page.

Thanks for any help,

Orville

Comment: What input format do you use? how that input format configured?

Comment: Is there any errors in error console ?

Comment: I am fairly new to Drupal development.  I am not sure what you mean by input format and error console.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a 401 error that only occurred when the user was not logged in. Changing the 'access arguments' string in the hook_services_resources array fixed the problem.